# axios POST шлёт только OPTIONS

Tags: api, vue.js, axios

Здравствуйте.

Есть такой метод:

```
sendMessage (data) {
  axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/messages`, {
    text: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e)
    })
}
```

Но на сервере отрабатывает только OPTIONS.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2017 22:41:13] "OPTIONS /messages HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Когда же я шлю при помощи [httpie](https://httpie.org/):

```
http http://127.0.0.1:5000/messages text=HelloWorld
```

То сперва отрабатывает `OPTIONS`, а затем `POST`:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2017 22:41:13] "OPTIONS /messages HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2017 22:52:45] "POST /messages HTTP/1.1" 201 -
```

То есть всё как и должно быть.

Сначала подумывал про `CORS` или на какое-то косяк на бекенде, и [задал вопрос](https://github.com/pyeve/eve/issues/1082) на github, на что получил ответ о том, что это скорее всего ошибка на клиенте.

Заранее спасибо за любую помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Я изменил Content-Type для всех запросов глобально и все заработало. Изначально я использувал Content-Type: application/json, но для коректной работы axios и отправки POST я задал Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Удачи